# Can we delete a column or change column order from Common Table Expression in My SQl?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table from my Query

[image]

I wanted to move the **'duration'** after the **'percent_monthly_changes**' column or delete the '**duration**' and add it after the '**percent_monthly_changes**'.

I tried Alter Table modify and stuff, browse the internet, but the syntax still won't work, is there a way to do it or i just have to add the column names manually by myself?

Thank You.

Anyway, here's my syntax, a little bit long so i  just take the latest syntax from the latest CTE

```
select *,
round(monthly_changes/lag(plays_,1) over (partition by film_title order by period_month)*100,2) as percent_monthly_changes,
sum(duration) over(partition by film_title order by period_month) as accum_duration
from cte3;
```

Comment: "I wanted to move the 'duration' after the 'percent_monthly_changes' column" - Why? Column order is not part of the relational model - it's an idiosyncracy of MySQL with no functional relevance I am aware of.

Comment: CTE is just a named subquery, which may appear in the `from`. You cannot alter it or drop something because it is not an object. Do not use columns you need.

Comment: You need to list the fields explucitely if you want to change the order they are appearing or remove one of them in a query, CTE or not.

Answer (score 0):

Like what Shadow mentioned, if it's just for viewing purpose (from executed syntax), just write the columns in `SELECT` instead of using asterisk (`SELECT *`).

So probably:

```
SELECT film_title, period_month, plays_, accum_plays, monthly_changes, 
       percent_monthly_contribution, 
       ROUND(monthly_changes/LAG(plays_,1) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY film_title 
                           ORDER BY period_month)*100,2) AS percent_monthly_changes,
       /*add "duration" column here or don't add at all*/ duration,
       SUM(duration) OVER (PARTITION BY film_title ORDER BY period_month) AS accum_duration
FROM cte3;
```